# Responsive images in CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor

Is there a way to set an image width to 100% of its parent?

At the minute I'm using Enhanced Image with a nicely styled figure tag for captions, but until the image fits the width of the figure it's pretty much useless!

Thanks!

Comment: "but until the image fits the width of" - of what?
Do you want image to have `width` 100% or you want the figure not to have `padding` or something else? Please edit the question and give more detailed description with a screen-sot if possible.

Comment: Oops, edited! But yes, I want the image width to be 100% of the figure it's in so that it will adapt to the Bootstrap breakpoints.

Answer (score 10):

Add this in your CSS file:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Or, try [this gist](https://gist.github.com/fabiomaggio/c2f4b84756cb4d82c0ae).

Comment: nice solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

After trying for so long I got a manual solution for making the image responsive in the CKEditor Django. After a adding the image in editor, put "style width:100%" manual in Image Properties

[image: 1]

This work in my case but we have to manually add this field.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for providing details and sorry for late reply.

In order to make the image 100% width of the `figure` please open `ckeditor\contents.css` file, find the selector for `figure` element and remove the `padding: 10px;` declaration. Next refresh your page and you should be good to go.

[image]